# Compare value of current row to average of all previous rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to compare the value of each date to the average value of all previous dates and calculate the percent change. For example, in the source table below, I would want to compare the value of 100 from December 2022 to the average of November, October, and September ((75+60+75)/3) to bring back the 0.43 change.

**Source Table**

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| December 2022 | 100 |
| November 2022 | 75 |
| October 2022 | 60 |
| September 2022 | 75 |

**Desired Output**

| Date | Value | Comparison |
| --- | --- | --- |
| December 2022 | 100 | 0.43 |
| November 2022 | 75 | 0.11 |
| October 2022 | 60 | -0.20 |
| September 2022 | 75 | - |

Comment: How do you get the `0.43` change?

Comment: @Zhorov I took the December 2022 value of 100 and compared it to the average of November, October, and September which is 70 (75+60+75 / 3). The 0.43 comes from (100-70)/70.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a windowed `AVG` with an `OVER` clause using the appropriate range of rows (`ORDER BY [Date] ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING`):

Test data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   (20221201, 100),
   (20221101, 75),
   (20221001, 60),
   (20220901, 75)
) v ([Date], [Value])
```

Statement:

```
SELECT [Date], [Value], ([Value] - [Average]) * 1.00 / [Average] AS [Comparison]
FROM (  
   SELECT
      *, 
      [Average] = AVG([Value]) OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
   FROM Data
) t  
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Result (without rounding):

| Date | Value | Comparison |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20221201 | 100 | 0.4285714285714 |
| 20221101 | 75 | 0.1194029850746 |
| 20221001 | 60 | -0.2000000000000 |
| 20220901 | 75 | *null* |

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you so much. I'm going to dig into this code more so I can understand the workings!!

Answer (score 1):

```sql
drop table #t
select *
into #t
from 
(
    VALUES  (1,N'December 2022', 100.0)
    ,   (2,N'November 2022', 75.0)
    ,   (3,N'October 2022', 60.0)
    ,   (4,N'September 2022', 75.0)
) t (sort, col1,col2)


select col2, (col2 - AVG(col2) OVER(ORDER BY sort DESC ROWS between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING)) / AVG(col2) OVER(ORDER BY sort DESC ROWS between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING)
,   AVG(col2) OVER(ORDER BY sort DESC)
from #t
order by sort
```

Something like this. watch out for 0 values though

Comment: I think it is `OVER (ORDER BY sort ASC ... ` instead of `OVER (ORDER BY sort DESC ... `.

Comment: well, the sort is 1, 2, 3, 4 but months are dec, nov, oct, sept, so i think it's ok

Comment: Yes, You are right, ordering by the additional `sort` column returns the correct results.